# Проблема с выводом в счетчике количества повторений символов

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы, память

Программа считает сколько раз повторялся тот или иной символ в текстовом документе.
Код компилируемый, но не выводит подсчитанное ни в csv ни в консоль.
Дебагинг ругается на цикл который записывает из массивов в csv.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int size = 1;
    char* symbolElem = new char[size];
    char currentSymbol, symbolForComparing;
    int* howManySymbMeet = new int[size];
    bool isLoopComplete = false;

    ifstream textFile;
    textFile.open("file.txt");

    while (textFile.get(currentSymbol)) {

        symbolForComparing = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            if (currentSymbol == symbolForComparing) {

                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    if (symbolElem[j] == symbolForComparing) {
                        (howManySymbMeet[j])++;
                        isLoopComplete = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!isLoopComplete) {
                    symbolElem[size] = symbolForComparing;
                    howManySymbMeet[size] = 0;
                    (howManySymbMeet[size])++;
                    size++;
                }

            }
            symbolForComparing++;
            isLoopComplete = false;
        }
    }
    textFile.close();

    ofstream csvFile;
    csvFile.open("output.csv");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        csvFile <<  symbolElem[i] << ", " << howManySymbMeet[i] << endl;
    }
    csvFile.close();

        delete [] symbolElem;
        delete [] howManySymbMeet;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выделяете массивы из 1 (прописью: *одного*) элемента:

```
int size = 1;
char* symbolElem = new char[size];
```

после чего начинаете писать в элементы с индексом явно больше 0... Получаете UB - неопределенное поведение, при котором может не работать что угодно.

Откровенно, я не понимаю, зачем для решения такой простой задачи такой сложный код, да и массива в 256 элементов достаточно, его можно не выделять динамически - просто нет смысла...

Вот вся программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    int count[256] = {};

    ifstream text("file.txt");
    while (text.get(c)) count[(unsigned char)c]++;

    ofstream csv("output.csv");
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        if (count[i] && i != '\n') csv << char(i) << ", " << count[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Всегда можно просто, но можно и сложно ) есть ли файл вы не проверили, открылся ли он - проверки тож нету) А вы мне про то, что я ещё исключения отпускаю говорите )))) давайте будем честно - у вас тоже стеб) и почему разделительно запятая с пробелом а не ;?

Comment: @Maggot Я не пытался писать сложно, излагал только принцип работы - набор статистики, не пытаясь привлекать неэффективный в данном случае `map` или еще какие-то ненужные сущности - например, добавление *текущего каталога* (!) к имени файла. Иногда я тоже могу решить простую задачку типа 2+2 с использованием каких-нибудь шаблонов и алгоритмов, которые совершенно не нужны, но в данном случае никакого стеба нет. Что до разделения запятой с пробелом - автору вопроса виднее, как *ему* нужно разделять, делал, как он.

Comment: спасибо ) можно долго спорить насчёт фантиков в коде, и да я где-то не прав усложняя код, но все же лёгких путей не ищем )))

Comment: @Maggot Да, но эффективные-то ищем? на файле в 55М мой код справился за 1,5с, ваш - за 5,8с, при этом попутно **не** посчитав ни пробелы, ни табуляции, ни символы новой строки. Это я уже второй раз намекаю - добавьте строку `in_stream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);` - кстати, и скорость сразу же вырастет.

Comment: тогда уж in_stream.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

Answer (score 0):

Вы используйте C++, Давайте попробуем использовать современный С++

На данный день, уже лет 15 не принято использовать оператор new в явном виде(допускается использовать его как размещающий). Пользуйтесь контейнерами и умными указателями

Алгоритм :

1) Проверяете что Ваш файл есть, и открываете его.

2) Заводите std::map для подсчета вхождений символов и заполняете его.

3) Создаете csv файл и дампите туду содержимое map

4) ПРОФИТ

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


std::map<unsigned char, std::size_t> CalcSymbls(std::filesystem::path f_path) {

    if (!std::filesystem::exists(f_path)) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"File not found!"};
    }

    std::ifstream in_stream(f_path, std::ios::out);
    if (!in_stream.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Error open file!"};
    }

    in_stream.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

    std::map<unsigned char, std::size_t> symbls;

    auto f_obj{[&](unsigned char ch){ symbls[ch]++;}};

    std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<char>(in_stream), std::istream_iterator<char>(), f_obj);

    return symbls;
}


void WriteCSV(std::filesystem::path out_file_path, std::map<unsigned char, std::size_t> data) {

    std::ofstream out_csv_stream(out_file_path, std::ios::out);

    if (!out_csv_stream.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Error open file"};
    }

    auto f_obj{[&](std::pair<unsigned char, std::size_t> val){ out_csv_stream << val.first << ";" << val.second << "\n";}};
    std::for_each(std::begin(data), std::end(data), f_obj);
}


int main() {

    std::string file_name{"data"};
    auto file_path{std::filesystem::current_path() / file_name};
    std::map<unsigned char, std::size_t> symbls;
    try {
        symbls = CalcSymbls(file_path);
    } catch (std::exception& exc) {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "unknown error ~ !"<< std::endl;
        return -10;
    }

    std::string out_name{"out.csv"};
    auto out_file_path{std::filesystem::current_path() / out_name};

    try {
        WriteCSV(out_file_path, symbls);
    } catch (std::exception& exc) {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << std::endl;
        return -2;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "unknown error ~ !"<< std::endl;
        return -10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Стеб неплохой, но если уж сказали `trow` - то стоит сказать и `try-catch`. И еще - а что такая ненависть к пробелам, что вы их за символы не считаете?...

Comment: @Harry upd answ